# Adding y-axes to a truncated barplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following data (4 columns and 6 rows of data):

```
    w   x   y   z
a   0.02    0.00    0.60    0.19
b   0.03    0.40    0.10    0.05
c   0.00    0.01    0.66    0.26
d   0.05    0.04    0.57    0.00
e   0.20    0.60    0.15    0.00
f   0.10    0.30    0.30    0.20
```

I have come up with this R script, which produces a nice truncated barplot by using ggplot:

```
## importing data

plot <- read.delim("data", row.names=1)
View(plot)


### loading required packages

if (!require("Rcpp")) {
  install.packages("Rcpp", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
  library("Rcpp")
}
library("Rcpp")

if (!require("ggplot2")) {
  install.packages("ggplot2", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
  library("ggplot2")
}
library("ggplot2")

if (!require("grid")) {
  install.packages("grid", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
  library("grid")
}
library("grid")


if (!require("reshape2")) {
  install.packages("reshape2", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
  library("reshape2")
}
library(reshape2)


## transpose "plot"
plot = t(plot)

plot <- melt(plot, id.vars=2:ncol(plot))


## running ggplot

bars = ggplot(plot[!is.na(plot$value),], aes(x = Var2, y = value, fill = factor(Var1))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=rainbow(length(levels(plot$Var1)))) + facet_grid(Var1~., as.table=FALSE, scale="free_y", space = "free_y") + theme_minimal() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=max(as.numeric(plot$Var2))+ 0.586, size=0.3) +
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, colour="black", vjust = 0.4, size=8), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        strip.text.y=element_text(size = 8, colour="black", family="",angle=00, hjust = 0),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.line=element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black", linetype = "solid"),
        axis.ticks.x=element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black", linetype = "solid"),
        panel.background=element_blank(), panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"))
bars

## exporting barplot "plot.png" to directory

#loading Cairo
if (!require("Cairo")) {
  install.packages("Cairo", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
  library("Cairo")
}
library("Cairo")

#preparing exporting
png(file="plot.png",type="cairo", width = 4, height = 4.2, units = 'in',pointsize=8,res=600) 

#exporting
barplot ; dev.off()
```

Result:

[image]

This is, for example "a" has a total score of 0.81 (of a maximum of 1), but split into 0.2 (red), 0, 0.6 (light blue) and 0.19 (dark blue) sub-columns.
The thing is, I would like to add a y-axis to each of the subcolumns section that include this information, like in this other image:

[image]

Do you know any option for ggplot that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly turned off the y-axis for your panels with:

`theme(..., axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.line.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), ...)`

Delete those lines and your figure should appear as you desire.

Comment: OMG you are so right, I must have removed them for some reason and then forgot about it... Thank you for noticing it!